# confused with an operator

Tags: c++, operators

I confused when I try to understand the code below. Can anyone explain this hack:

```
a.*b
```

Or if `a` is a pointer to a class:

```
a->*b
```

Comment: It isn't a hack; it's a pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of those operators are used to dereference a pointer-to-member. Unlike regular pointers, pointer-to-members cannot be *dereferenced* by themselves, but must be applied to an actual object of the type. Those binary operators pick the object (or pointer) in the left hand side and apply the pointer to member to it.

```
struct test {
    int a, b, c;
};
int main() {
   int test::*ptr;
   ptr = &test::a;
   test t;
   t.*ptr = 5;         // set t.a to 5
   ptr = &test::b;
   test *p = &t;
   p->*ptr = 10;       // set t.b to 10 through a pointer
}
```